# android:background does not fill_parent or fitXY

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I'm attempting to set my background image however it will not seem to fill to the edge of the screen and I'm not sure why. I'm pretty sure those two parameters have worked for me in the past.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM5OJ.png

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ui2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ui2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. first see this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ui2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Based on your XML you set a margin on your relative layout with 20dp left and right then added a `linear layout` with background image that match the parent wherein the parent is the `relative layout`. Remove the margin of the relative layout then it will fit the screen then all of the content that needs to have a margin of 20dp left and right must be inside the linear layout to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

> use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ui2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ui2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ui2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding` instead of `margin` on your `RelativeLayout` as follows

```
android:layout_paddingLeft="20dp"
android:layout_paddingRight="20dp"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

in your Layout to

```
       android:paddingLeft="20dp"
       android:paddingRight="20dp"
```

Hope this helps